# $routeProvider is not able to access html template

Tags: angularjs, ng-view, route-provider, angularjs-ng-route, ng-controller

I have added both the files of angular.min.js and angular-route.min.js but still not working

app.js code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[
'ngRoute',
'artistControllers'
]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.
when('/list',{
    templateUrl:'partials/list.html',
    controller:'ListController'
}).
otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/list'
});
}]);
```

controller.js code:

```
var artistControllers = angular.module('artistControllers',[]);

artistControllers.controller('ListController', function($scope,$http){

$http.get('js/data.json').then(function(response){
    $scope.artist=response.data;
    $scope.artistOrder='name';
}); 
});
```

Comment: mmm have you tried to set the relative path of your html view files from the root of the app? ..like templateUrl:'./app/views/partials/list.html',

Comment: What do the logs say? Is controller.js loaded before app.js in HTML? does partials/list.html resolve? What if you use template: '<h1>hello</h1>' vs. templateUrl temporarily -> do you get hello?..Are you loading angular.js before angular-route..?

Comment: please post the error message you are getting

Comment: Using HTML5 mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application (e.g. index.html). Requiring a `<base>` tag is also important for this case, as it allows AngularJS to differentiate between the part of the url that is the application base and the path that should be handled by the application. [AngularJS Developer Guide - HTML5 Mode Server Side](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#server-side).

Comment: Please check if partials folder is in public folder

Comment: @RahulNaik no errors are coming the page is completely blank

Comment: @korcan yes it is on same level as where index.html file is their

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi : i have kept partials folder on the same level as where index.html file is their

Comment: I am running the code on local server and the below link is coming in the address bar http://localhost/angular-bs/#!/list

Comment: You need it from the root of your webservet folder... pur your error console log if there is one

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/eH6PtL?p=preview this is workin plnkr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you did not include your controller.js to your html

```
<script src="controller.js"></script>
```

look at this plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/eH6PtL?p=preview

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>AngularJs-Bootstrap</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container" ng-view"></div>

</body>
</html>

Comment: i have added it

Comment: It is very strange , did you look at what is the difference working plkr and your's

Comment: I recommend you to change <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script> <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"> with those in plnkr

Comment: I got the error it was in <div class="container" ng-view"> i have added double quote after ng-view. Problem solved

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will be help for you.

Remove 'artistControllers' from array:

angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','artistControllers']);

try this one

from angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

and check you file path for partials/list.html from the root of your application.

Comment: I have removed artistControllers but still not working

Comment: Can you give me root template structure?